# 1 button wi-fi connection reset

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, connection

I need a way to instantly reset connection to current wi-fi network.
As in: disconnect->connect again to the same one.
Preferably as fast as possible and very simple (1 button).
Any ideas for a script, a program, anything that does that?

My problem in general is that my connection tends to lag the game I'm playing and I usually need to disconnect and connect to my network or else I'm stuck (even though browser, for example, works fine).
I however believe that given my problem's nature (can't predict when it will happen, completely random) it's just too difficult to find the cause.

Thanks for your time.

Windows 10 btw

Comment: WPS fits your requirements.  It's also extremely insecure, like anyone can gain access to your network, within 60 seconds insecure.  **You should absolutely not enable WPS.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately the router is in another room so even if I was desperate it would take me too long to use it as a means to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ramhound stated earlier in his comment, that Wi-Fi Protected Setup (WPS) will fulfill your need. But WPS is extremely insecure. There are WPS buttons in routers which we can press and easily reconnect to the router without password. And the WPS pins are 8 digit pins, but only the first 4 digits are checked. So it can be easily brute forced. So you must disable WPS.

But as you have stated in your question

> a script, a program, anything that does that?

So you can use a batch script that stops the wireless interface and after a little amount of time enables the interface again:

```
@echo off
netsh wlan disconnect
ping localhost -n <seconds> -w 1000 >nul 2>&1
netsh wlan connect
```

Replace  with the seconds to wait between reconnection interval. Save it as .bat file and place it in suitable location, such as desktop. And click it to reset connection. As it is the default wifi, each time you turn on wireless interface, it will auto connect to that wifi.

Comment: Alright, unfortunately the script only disconnects me from wi-fi ("Disconnection request was completed successfully for interface "Wi-Fi 2".") and nothing after.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo fixed it

Comment: Ok I got it to work, I had to add SSID and network name and it runs perfectly. I deleted the entire "ping" line tho, was it necessary? Can you explain what it does?

Comment: @momtorgano the `ping` is just to add a delay between the other commands and is not required

Comment: @DavidPostill thank you for explaining the ping part. Netsh commands turn off and on wireless interface.